# How to use Google app script to automatically border line below When Value Changes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to add a border line below the row whenever column C value changes.

I haven’t touched macro for a long time, this is a script I put together but it doesn’t work as expected. Anyone know where the problem is? Thanks!

```
function underline() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() + i, 3) != sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() + i+1, 3)) {
        sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() + i, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
        spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
         }
  }

};
```

Comment: I understand that you want to add: **one** single, **page-width** line under **any** one cell when it is edited. Correct?

Comment: Yep one under any cell that are different from next row rather than edited: If c2=‘zoo’ c3=‘zoo’, c4=‘garden’ and c5=’forest', then add one border line below row 3 and 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code is a bit convoluted, doing a lot with a single `if` statement. I took the liberty to separate the complicated bit into a distinct function, `findOriginal(cell)`. The following code adds one line:

```
function findOriginal(cell) { //offsets given cell until finds new content
  while (cell.getValue() == cell.offset(1,0).getValue()) cell = cell.offset(1,0);
  return cell;
}

function underline() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      cell = spreadsheet.getSelection().getCurrentCell();

  cell = findOriginal(cell);

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()) // setting the range to border
  .setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, 
             '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID); // you wrote this line
};
```

Comment: I’m not sure it worked. I intend to apply borderline to every row with the value in C column different from next row, so there’re supposed to be lots of lines. Do i need a loop somewhere? Thanks

Comment: however, thanks to ur reply, I've figured it out. so thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you found it! consider accepting / upvoting my answer if it helped.